# Is there a way to reset Kite Autocomplete's AI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, autocomplete, artificial-intelligence

I'm wondering if I can **reset the training of Kite's AI** that uses my code. I want to do this because I want to change my code style and there is some stuff that I quit doing.

Take `xrange` for example; it's deprecated in python3 (I'm a python coder). So, I want to reset all of the data it learned from me as if I just got it again. I don't want to uninstall and reinstall it.

Is uninstalling the Sublime Text/Atom plugins and reinstalling them would do the trick? Or is it not possible?

And for the specs, I got a MacOS Catalina (10.15.5 (19F96)), non-pro and no account for Kite, and Kite version 0.20200609.2.

**I want to know if there's an official way, *not some file removing magic.***

But if some file removing magic is necessary, then I'm fine.

Also, I wonder if just removing and reinstalling the plugins for editors would do the trick...

---

<sub>I want a coniacal answer.</sub>

Comment: Which operating system are you on? It's possible that there is some file that you can delete to remove kite's data without removing kite itself

Comment: I added the specs

Comment: I don't think there's an official way, sorry
I don't use a mac, so I can't give you a magic file-removing way either... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a new account. I was in the same situation once and honestly, nothing seemed to help. I tried to uninstall and reinstall but as vague as that other answer is, it didn't work because they probably store the data and train a model for each individual user account unique to them without a kill-switch so probably the only way is to create a new account unless of course there's another workaround that they make us aware of which at the time being, I'm pretty sure does not exist.

Comment: I guess this is the only helpful answer

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and reinstall is the only way as of today it seems.

for more info see [Kite's help](https://help.kite.com/article/68-how-to-uninstall-kite)

Comment: Clarify your answer, please. By removing the plugins?